# Fog glow and motion blur in cel shading

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I'm designing a cel shaded phoenix in Cycles. I have used particles as flames as opposed to using the smoke simulator. Now, i want to add motion blur and fog glow to those particles to make them look more fire-like. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

[image]

This is my basic set up:

[image]

Comment: hello again :) are you satisfied with the motion blur effect from my previous answer? Or do you need something else?

Comment: @LukeD hey, yeah, you used the 'Motion Blur' from the 'Render' Tab, I want the particles to have a trailing effect. Also, notice because of the 'Motion Blur' some of the free style outlines are empty-ish. (Sorry, if my project is being too demanding) XD

Comment: I don't think I get it right... Could you explain those outlines based on screenshot?

Comment: @LukeD https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVf9r.jpg look at the particles outside the red region, they are kinda empty.

Comment: ok, now I see it. It seems like motion blur affects only inside of the cubes and cell shading is added after motion. Possible solution could be to make layer with moving paricles without Cell Shading to keep motion blur, and another one with Cell Shading but withouth movement. Il'l look into this later if you can't figure it out till then.

Comment: @LukeD oh, ok.. and then merge the layers... got it.. I'll try that out and another idea I have. Will update the result.Let you know of the outcome. Thanks again, mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do the motion blur in the compositor. Just check the Vector pass and plug it into a [vector blur node](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/compositing/types/filter/vector_blur.html) and you're done:

[image: screenshot of the result]

If you want fog glow, mask the glowing materials by setting the material ID on the materials that should be glowing. Add a glare filter and add it to the rest of the image. The filter resolution is set to low because it increases the effect's size (I really don't like how you control the size of fog glow in Blender). Consider using a blur node as an alternative if you're not happy with the results.

[image: fog glow]

If you have a lot of render time, also consider using the *not-faking-anything* method:

- Make the cube's outline *real* instead of using freestyle. This can be achieved through texturing, vector paint and perhaps clever shading.
- Add a Volume Scatter node as the world's background. Volume scattering (and absorbtion) are basically physical fog.
- Adapt your lighting (increase the emission shader). Volumetrics really suck lighting
- Enable *real*, Cycles-rendered motion blur.

With this, your render time will explode. But it will look nice :)

Comment: that's one down and for that you have my thanks , any luck with the fog glow, though?

Comment: I'm working on it.

Comment: @Tejas That is what you want? I've had another thing in mind. Blurred trails and sharp cubes.

Comment: @LukeD hmm..ok, I listening... fire it at me

Comment: @Tejas First of all if you want fog glow based on piegames method, after Vector Blur node add Filter > Glare set it to Fog Glow and Treshold to 0.1. I'm fiddling with my method now.

Comment: And by the way, never use an uneven number of samples. It always gives you way more noise than the even ones.

Comment: @LukeD thanks both for your help in this my only regret here that i can't credit you both equally on this site :)